# Obtener registro de un arreglo - javaScript

Tags: javascript

Deseo obtener datos específicos de un registro almacenado en un array, tengo lo siguiente:

```
[
{"CODIGO":"930101142","DESCRIPCION":"ALFAJORES CHOCO CHIPS D CECI","MEDIDA":"UNI","CANTIDAD":15.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"A"},
{"CODIGO":"600602001","DESCRIPCION":"ACEITE X 1LT","MEDIDA":"UNI","CANTIDAD":15.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"A"},
{"CODIGO":"600602059","DESCRIPCION":"ATUN X 24 UNID","MEDIDA":"CAJ","CANTIDAD":5.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"A"},
{"CODIGO":"330201061","DESCRIPCION":"BOLSA 31/2 X 8 X 2  PQTE 200 UNID.CHIFLE","MEDIDA":"PAQ","CANTIDAD":13.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"B"},
{"CODIGO":"600201002","DESCRIPCION":"CAMOTE BLS (KG )","MEDIDA":"KGR","CANTIDAD":20.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"C"}
];
```

De este json deseo obtener solo un registro y obtener su 'medida'  y 'cantidad' para esto yo ya tengo el ID que viene a ser 'CODIGO'.

Gracias..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qué tal, intenta esto:

```
var arreglo =
[
{"CODIGO":"930101142","DESCRIPCION":"ALFAJORES CHOCO CHIPS D CECI","MEDIDA":"UNI","CANTIDAD":15.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"A"},
{"CODIGO":"600602001","DESCRIPCION":"ACEITE X 1LT","MEDIDA":"UNI","CANTIDAD":15.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"A"},
{"CODIGO":"600602059","DESCRIPCION":"ATUN X 24 UNID","MEDIDA":"CAJ","CANTIDAD":5.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"A"},
{"CODIGO":"330201061","DESCRIPCION":"BOLSA 31/2 X 8 X 2  PQTE 200 UNID.CHIFLE","MEDIDA":"PAQ","CANTIDAD":13.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"B"},
{"CODIGO": "600201002","DESCRIPCION":"CAMOTE BLS (KG )","MEDIDA":"KGR","CANTIDAD":20.000000,"STOCK":"SI","ORD_LETRA":"C"}
];

var posicionDeRegistro = arreglo.findIndex(x => x.CODIGO === "600602001");
console.log(arreglo[posicionDeRegistro].DESCRIPCION); ***//Aquí obtienes el campo descipción***
```

`var arreglo` es el arreglo donde lo tienes almacenado.
`findIndex` busca la posición del registro que coincide con el parámetro (ej. "600602001").
Después simplemente seleccionas la posición en tu arreglo usando la variable `posicionDeRegistro`

Puedes checarlo probarlo tal cual lo puse en: *https://jsfiddle.net/*

Comment: Podrias explicar como esto soluciona el problema? mira por favor [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el método `filter()` de este modo:

> El método `filter`es un bucle que iterará sobre los datos del objeto, por cada iteración podremos acceder al valor por medio de `dato`  y apartir de aquí podemos acceder a su *key* donde buscaremos la igualdad con un `ID` específico.

```
let buscador = datos.filter(dato => dato.CODIGO === "930101142")

console.log(buscador)
```

Lo cual nos da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
[[object Object] {
  CANTIDAD: 15,
  CODIGO: "930101142",
  DESCRIPCION: "ALFAJORES CHOCO CHIPS D CECI",
  MEDIDA: "UNI",
  ORD_LETRA: "A",
  STOCK: "SI"
}]
```

Al objeto anterior necesitamos ahora iterarlo para recuperar los valores deseados a través de su *key*, de este modo:

```
buscador.forEach(dato => {
  console.log(dato["MEDIDA"])
  console.log(dato["CANTIDAD"])
})
```

Lo anterior lo trabajamos obteniendo `variable` que representa cada valor o valores recuperados por cada iteración y el nombre de la clave que deseamos vidualizar

Con lo cual obtenemos como resultado:

```
"UNI"
15
```

O puedes meter toda la lógica dentro de una función y solo pasarle como argumento el `CODIGO` por el cual deseas filtrar los datos, representado por la variable  `id`

```
const buscador = (id) => {
  let element = datos.filter(dato => dato.CODIGO === id)
  return `La cantidad es: ${element[0]["CANTIDAD"]} y la medida es: ${element[0]["MEDIDA"]}`
}

console.log(buscador("930101142"))
```

Y el resultado es este:

> "La cantidad es: 15 y la medida es: UNI"